# SQL counting survey results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question regarding counting survey results and having the data in columns instead of rows...a.VARNAME is a question and a.value is the answer. I am trying to count how many answers of 0,1,2,3,4,5  for each question. I get the result I want but it is all in a single row...how can I get the quesion 'varname' as a column header and then Answered 0,1,2,3,4, as rows??

```
select 
sum(CASE WHEN a.VARNAME = 'R2' and a.value = '0' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Answered 0',
sum(CASE WHEN a.VARNAME = 'R2' and a.value = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Answered 1',
sum(CASE WHEN a.VARNAME = 'R2' and a.value = '2' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Answered 2',
sum(CASE WHEN a.VARNAME = 'R2' and a.value = '3' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Answered 3',
sum(CASE WHEN a.VARNAME = 'R2' and a.value = '4' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Answered 4',
sum(CASE WHEN a.VARNAME = 'R2' and a.value = '5' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Answered 5',
sum(CASE WHEN a.VARNAME = 'R2' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Total',
sum(CASE WHEN a.VARNAME = 'A1' and a.value = '0' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Answered 0 ',
sum(CASE WHEN a.VARNAME = 'A1' and a.value = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Answered 1 ',
sum(CASE WHEN a.VARNAME = 'A1' and a.value = '2' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Answered 2 ',
sum(CASE WHEN a.VARNAME = 'A1' and a.value = '3' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Answered 3',
sum(CASE WHEN a.VARNAME = 'A1' and a.value = '4' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Answered 4 ',
sum(CASE WHEN a.VARNAME = 'A1' and a.value = '5' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Answered 5 '
from survey_patient p
inner join survey_analysis a
  on p.survey_id = a.survey_id
inner join survey_question_map q
  on a.varname = q.varname and p.[service] = q.[service]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the *counts* in each row for the varname.  How about this?

```
select a.VarName, vals.value,
       sum(case when vals.value = a.value then 1 else 0 end) as TheCount
from (select '0' as value union all
      select '1' union all
      select '2' union all
      select '3' union all
      select '4' union all
      select '5'
     ) as vals cross join
     survey_patient p inner join
     survey_analysis a
     on p.survey_id = a.survey_id inner join
     survey_question_map q
     on a.varname = q.varname and p.[service] = q.[service];
group by a.varname, vals.value;
```

You are only pulling data from `survey_analysis`.  If the other tables are not needed, you can simplify this to:

```
select a.VarName, vals.value,
       sum(case when vals.value = a.value then 1 else 0 end) as TheCount
from (select '0' as value union all
      select '1' union all
      select '2' union all
      select '3' union all
      select '4' union all
      select '5'
     ) as vals cross join
     survey_analysis a
group by a.varname, vals.value;
```

Comment: I use the other tables in my where clause but I left all that out...thank you very much for the help...

Answer (score 1):

My first job right out of college was to work at the start up that did medical surveys.

We had a report that was an item analysis.  Basically, count +1 each answer per value (0..5) as a sub total and calculate a overall total answers.  Divide the sub-total by the overall total to get the average and print it next to the survey questions with a nice little bar chart.

**I think this is what your are trying to do?**

Let's create a little test database.

```
-- Just play
USE Tempdb;
Go

-- Create the table
CREATE TABLE survey_analysis 
(
  -- links to survey_patient (FK)
  survey_id INT not null,

  -- links to survey_question_map (FK)
  varname VARCHAR(20),

  -- actual answer (0=n/a)
  varvalue INT DEFAULT 0
);
GO

-- Remove data when playing
truncate table survey_analysis;
GO

-- Create some data
insert into survey_analysis values
  (1, 'R2', 1),
  (1, 'A1', 1),
  (2, 'R2', 2),
  (2, 'A1', 2),
  (3, 'R2', 3),
  (3, 'A1', 3),
  (4, 'R2', 4),
  (4, 'A1', 4),
  (5, 'R2', 5),
  (5, 'A1', 5),
  (6, 'X1', 1),
  (6, 'X2', 2),
  (7, 'R2', 5);
GO

-- Show the data
select * from survey_analysis;
GO
```

While you have survey_patient and survey_question_map tables, they are just background noise.  You want to calculate your totals on the survey_analysis table.

```
-- 
-- Get sub-total by question (varname), answer(myvalue), and running total
--

SELECT  
    A.varname,
    Q.myvalue, 
    Q.myanswer, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Q.myvalue = A.varvalue THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as mysubtotal,
    SUM(1) as mytotal
FROM 

-- Driver table if we do not have all combinations
  (
    VALUES 
      (0, 'Answered 0'),
      (1, 'Answered 1'),
      (2, 'Answered 2'),
      (3, 'Answered 3'),
      (4, 'Answered 4'),
      (5, 'Answered 5')
  ) AS Q (myvalue, myanswer)

CROSS JOIN survey_analysis as A

-- Filter for questions with 0-5 answers
WHERE 
    A.varname in ('A1', 'R2')
GROUP BY
    A.varname,
    Q.myvalue, 
    Q.myanswer;
GO
```

Here is how I solved your problem.

1 - Create a **DERIVED** table for Questions (Q) that have 5 answers.

2 - Use a **CROSS JOIN** on survey_analysis so that we are guaranteed to have all combinations.

3 - Filter using a **WHERE** clause.  Do not include questions with < 5 answers

4 - **GROUP BY** the question, answer, answer label.

5 - Include both a sub-total and overall total by item to show statistics.

If you have a bunch questions with varying number of answers: repeat the query; adjust the derived table for the number of answers; use the UNION ALL to combine all results into one result set; add some id like question # so that you can order the final results.

[image]